# Facebook Analytics 'Current URL' doesn't work...?

Tags: facebook-analytics

It seems that filtering data, eg. creating a segment, or defining a funnel step, cannot use the 'Current URL' field. Or at least, it doesn't seem to work for me at all.

Am I missing something? Is this just broken?

Kind Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [docs](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1012300315565213) that might help you. You can also play around with the [Demo Event Source Group](https://www.facebook.com/analytics/1701892993437661/) and create a segment like so:

[image: Segment by Current URL]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're seeing the same issue as I am. Surely someone out the 196K visitors loaded the catalog page, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out the https://www.

That sometimes seems to help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - they're selected from a pre-populated field in Facebook Analytics (so I can't edit them).